# How to instrument binary (dll) using NCover/xunit

Tags: c#, xunit.net, ncover

I am new to NCover and want to instrument a dll using NCover for code coverage. Our tests are written using xUnit.net, can someone please help me out in doing this?

I need to do code coverage using command line; we are using VSInstr/vsperfcmd ( http://namgivu.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/how-to-get-unit-testing-code-coverage-run-from-command-line/ ) at present but exploring NCover for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NCover here to help. This may prompt more questions :-) but is a good start. Please reach out to us at support@ncover.com if you have more.

First, create a working command line to run the xunit tests.

Then, create an NCover project to cover xunit. A regex on the xunit process should be all that's required. I don't know what the xunit process is called, but this will be something like:
Match type=Regex, Process mathcimg="xunit"

Next, put the NCover Run command in front of the xunit command. Here's our help doc on NCover Run:
http://www.ncover.com/support/docs/extras/command-line/ncover-run